# Update context depending on axios response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm facing a problem,

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call.

Apparently it's breaking the rule of "Do not call in event handlers." ? I can't find an alternative to update my context. I need the context, to update several components like *menu.js*, to manage the accessibility to private routes...

My *AuthContext.js*

```js
export const AuthContext = React.createContext({
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    setToken: () => {}
});
```

My *LoginForm.js*

```js
class LoginForm extends Component {
  authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: 'eve.holt@reqres.in',
      password: 'cityslicka',
      error: ''
    };

    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
    this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://reqres.in/api/login',
      data: {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      }
    }).then(result => {
      if (result.status === 200) {
        this.authContext.setToken(result.data.token);
        localStorage.setItem('token', result.data.token);
      } else { }
    });
  }

 ...
}
```

I've found some answers but **I can't understand** or solve my problem. If you can explain your answers, I'd appreciate it

Thanks for helping

Comment: Hooks cannot be used inside class components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite your classical component into functional component, since hooks are not designed to work inside classes.
Check out react doc's rule of hooks:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions